# $routeProvider not invoking correctly

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm a little stuck with a route provider i'm working with within my application. I'm using grunt to uglify all this so I'm starting to wonder if thats part of it?

Anyways some code samples with the app.config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    controller: 'theAppController',
    template: ''
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/default'
});
```

The controller (for the time being located in app.js)

```
app.controller("theAppController", function($scope){
    console.log("I'm an App controller!!!!!");
});
```

During app.run I'm calling this:

```
.run(
    ['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function($route, $rootScope, $location) {
        console.log($route);
    }]
)
```

Which is outputting

```
Object {routes: Object, reload: function}
current: e.extend.e.extend
    $$route: Object
        controller: "theAppController"
        keys: Array[0]
        originalPath: "/home"
        regexp: /^\/home$/
        reloadOnSearch: true
        template: ""
        __proto__: Object
locals: Object
params: Object
pathParams: Object
__proto__: Object
reload: function (){u=!0;a.$evalAsync(l)}
routes: Object
__proto__: Object
```

As a quick test to see if $routeProvider was actually hit I ran (home1)

```
$routeProvider.when('/home1', {
    controller: 'theAppController',
    template: ''
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/default'
});
```

Which hit the otherwise correctly and changed the url to /default

I can see that by dumping the route service, the current route is set correctly but neither the template (which is empty, although tested and nothing is shown) nor the controller for that route is loaded, I can't even get an error using an incorrect controller loaded.

Any thoughts on this?

quick edit: I'm also within my html using

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: What's in `$$route: Object` ? A fiddle would be nice as well :)

Comment: Sorry, messed up the indent. Its the current route. I can't fiddle this because it's something specific to my application setup I feel. I've made a quick simple prototype but it works... I'm starting to think it's the uglify. I should maybe try ngmin before hand

Comment: Wait, if you are not using ngmin (or something similar), then `controller('...', function($scope){` is definitely going to break. `$scope` is **not** an argument passed which can have an arbitrary name. It is Dependency-Injected, so it's name is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure what your question is asking exactly, but i sense you are unable to load anything when being redirected to /default, and this is because you aren't handling the route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    controller: 'theAppController',
    template: ''
}).when('/default', {
    controller: 'theDefaultController',
    template: '<p>You have been redirected to the default route<p>'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/default'
});

app.controller("theDefaultController", function($scope){
    console.log("I'm the Default controller!!!!!");
});
```